# Excel VBA scrollscreen automatically

Tags: vba, scroll, screen

Let's say the range `(A1:A200)` contains a descending order of numbers (from 200 to 1) and I have implemented conditional formatting on the range.

When any cell in A1:A200 matches the source data `(Cell B1)`, which is continuously updated, it will be highlighted in Yellow in its background.

My question is How can I write a code to scroll the screen to the matched cell(highlighted yellow) and position it in the middle of my screen?

I don't want the `".select"` function as the matched cell is keep changing and the target cell may not be the active cell. Much appreciate if anyone can offer some help to me. Many thanks!

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried the following code, but it is not what I want

Comment: Sub center_it()
Application.Goto reference:=ActiveCell, Scroll:=True
With ActiveWindow
i = .VisibleRange.rows.Count / 2
j = .VisibleRange.columns.Count / 2
.SmallScroll Up:=i, ToLeft:=j
End With
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Adapted the following code from [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/zoom.htm). I modified the original code to **not** select the cell we scroll to, as you specified. I've tested it with Excel 2010 and it works for me.

```
Sub ScrollToCell(OnCell As Range)

  Dim VisRows As Integer
  Dim VisCols As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  '
  ' Switch over to the OnCell's workbook and worksheet.
  '
  OnCell.Parent.Parent.Activate
  OnCell.Parent.Activate
  '
  ' Get the number of visible rows and columns for the active window.
  '
  With ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
      VisRows = .Rows.Count
      VisCols = .Columns.Count
  End With
  '
  ' Now, determine what cell we need to scroll to. The ScrollRow and
  ' ScrollColumn methods will place that cell reference in the upper left
  ' corner of the screen, so that reference needs to be VisRows/2 above and
  ' VisCols/2 columns to the left of the cell we want to center on.
  ' Use the Max function to ensure we're not trying to scroll a cell in
  ' row <=0 or column <=0.
  '
  ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(1, OnCell.Row + (OnCell.Rows.Count / 2) - (VisRows / 2))
  ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(1, OnCell.Column + (OnCell.Columns.Count / 2)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((VisCols / 2), 0)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

To call it, you can do:

```
CenterOnCell Range("S50")
```

I'm sure you can now adapt this code to suit your own specific requirements.

Comment: Hi Djikay, the code works great, but whatif the target range is keep changing as the source data (Cell B1) is being updated? It may not be fixed at Range"S50". Thank you

Comment: @user3819090 I guess you'd have to detect yourself which cell has changed, then you pass its reference to this function and it gets centred. I can't think of an automatic way for Excel to do this for you. The function will also work with a range of cells, so if you know the range of cells that can change, at least you could centre on the whole range. I'm sorry, I can't think of another way to do this automatically.

Comment: Hi Djikay, I have figured out to tell the Excel returns a row number which can be used for the code to recognize the recentering task. As you can sugguest "ScrollToCell ("S50)" to call the procedure, how can I change the range(active cell) by reference to a range's value instead? It seems a silly question, I hope you dun't mind

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `ScrollToCell` takes a `Range` object. If you have a range you want to scroll to, just pass it in there. The range can represent a single cell or multiple cells, it doesn't matter.